# How to make it so everyone can access you database on an application C.#

Tags: mysql

Basically the title says it all. I’ve been trying to make it so my friends can use my apps i made in visual studio but it never works because (a guess) they cant connect to the database because it connects to local host. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: the best way is to acquire webspace with  mysql and only access data per php script. Everything else needs careful planing and a lot of knowledge about security and constant patching even in a demilitarised zone would your server be under constant strain.

Comment: You would need to host the database online somewhere, e.g. in cloud or other hosting. Be careful about security though, as mentioned. On Azure and others you can do whitelisting of IPs and other security measures

Comment: Or...if the app doesn't need to share data with other copies of the app (i.e. it can be standalone), then just distribute a copy of the database along with the app and each user will get their own private database. If you can switch to using something like SQLite or SQL Server LocalDB then that job is much simpler. (I'm assuming these are Windows apps although you didn't say)

Comment: Would there be a way to host it on my computer?

Comment: Not unless you want to expose your home computer to the public internet (this is generally done by enabling port-forwarding on your router)...I wouldn't really recommend it. Also, unless you never ever switch off your machine, then sometimes your friends are going to lose access to the database. Consider your home computer to be the development environment. The live environment accessed by others should be somewhere else (using either of the two suggestions I made, depending on your requirements).

Comment: Is there a tutorial on how to do that?

Comment: Which of my suggestions are you thinking of? You can probably Google for ideas fairly easily anyway

Comment: The last one. Hosting  it on my home computer.

Comment: Find a tutorial about port forwarding on your router. There will be plenty if you take the time to search. But seriously it's a security risk, I don't recommend it unless you are sure you know what you're doing and can keep your environment safe.